# Reduce spinnaker log level

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Spinnaker logs an unholy amount of INFO messages. I could not find any documentation on how to raise the minimum log level of spinnaker to, let's say, WARN.

How can I set a different default log level for spinnaker, preferably using halyard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can amend spinnaker-local.yml:

```
logging:
  level:
    com:
      netflix:
        spinnaker: DEBUG
      retrofit: TRACE
```

You can update it to log only WARN or ERROR events and higher.